Creating particles in Reality Composer pro
I am simulating an immersive space journey. I need a particles effect to go towards the user, to simulate the travel (conceptually similar to this).
I built that in code, but I don't want to invent the wheel again, in fact I am pretty sure that the same result or a better one can be achieved by using Reality Composer Pro.
I'll leave the code I created so that my goal is clearer.
/// This creates particles for the immersive travel. They are thrown at the user to simulate the journey
    /// - Returns: the anchor entity point of where the range of particles should spawn
    func createParticle() -> AnchorEntity {
        
        //some parameters
        let particleEntity = ModelEntity(
            mesh: mesh,
            materials: [material]
        )
        
        //some logic
        var randomX: Float
        var randomY: Float
        
        repeat {
            randomX = Float.random(in: -4...4)
        } while randomX >= -0.3 && randomX <= 0.3
        
        repeat {
            randomY = Float.random(in: -2...2)
        } while randomY >= 0.7 && randomY <= 1
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: [randomX, randomY, -20.0])
        anchor.addChild(particleEntity)
        
        return anchor
    }

I then call this function through a timer to create a particle each refresh rate.
EDIT: I feel my question is different because it is not some animation that is originally imported from Reality Composer Pro. I might be wrong because animations are not my forte

This question is similar to: Particle system in RealityKit. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The search term you're looking for is "particle emitter". You'll find several dozen WWDC sessions on the Apple Developer app that cover Reality Composer Pro.
